# uploaded binary for review, how to change when it will be visible

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've uploaded binary to Appstore for review and approval. How to change following settin now:
When they approve it, I don't want to be automaticaly be visible on AppStore. I want to change the setting so i can put it on Appstore when I decide.

It asked me for this setting before binary is uploiaded, but can i change it now?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. iTunesConnect will only ask you this once. Your update will released once approved.

Just reject the binary and upload again, you will be asked the question again.

Answer (score 0):

You **Can Not** do this.

Check the list here in detail :-

[Editing and Updating App Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Goto rights and pricing info screen (where you can select pricing tiers for your app), and then either choose your app's availability date or deselect all countries from appstores.

The following text was from Apple' doc.

If you choose to automatically release your app update, it will go live as soon as it is approved by Apple (pending the availability date you have set).

If you choose to control the version’s release, your app status will change to Pending Developer Release after it has been approved by App Review, indicating that you can release it to the App Store whenever you are ready.

When you're ready for your app update to go live on the App Store, you are responsible for releasing your app version to the App Store.